# Sending ' :new ' trigger object as my object

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

In my DB i have class, for example, 'human' consist of 'name' and 'age' fields.
Also there is a trigger with following code:

`myObj := new human();`
`myObj.name := :new.name;`
`myObj.age := :new.age;`

`SomeProc(myObj);`

Is it any way to write something like:

`SomeProc((human):new)` ?

Comment: In DB you have a class or package?

Comment: Search Oracle Docs for objects and collections and you will have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no need to keep a variable of an object instance in the trigger body for further reference, yes you can do an implicit call of default constructor the following way:

```
SomeProc(MyObj(:new.name, :new.age));
```